# In Electron Main Process, I want to execute external CLI app like kubectl

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, electron

### Problem

I want to automate CLI tools (like kubectl) with electron GUI. It is working well in development environment... But in production build my app can't find programs in PATH.

#### in development

I'm using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) in electron. But exec method is my own implementation. ([shelljs exec electron compatibility issue](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/wiki/Electron-compatibility)) It [spawn child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) then resolve with stdout.

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

exports.childProcessWithResult = async function (args) {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let result = ''

        const res = spawn('sh', args, { shell: true })
        res.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
          result += `${data}`
        })
        res.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
          result += `error: ${data}`
          console.error(data.toString('utf-8'))
        })
        res.on('error', (error) => {
          console.error(error.toString('utf-8'))
        })
        res.on('close', (code) => {
          resolve(result)
        })
      })
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
}
```

`npm run electron:build`
`"electron:build": "npm run build && npx electron ."`

On Developer Tools (via IPC)

```js
await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"which kubectl"')
// '/usr/local/bin/kubectl'
await window.electronAPI.shell.which('kubectl')
// '/usr/local/bin/kubectl'
await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"command -v kubectl"')
// '/usr/local/bin/kubectl'
console.log(await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"ls"'))
/*
README.md
arkit.json
auth.json
auto-imports.d.ts
coverage
dist
...
*/
```

#### in production build

I'm using electron builder. Target is MacOS dmg format. The app is installed and I click the icon to run my app.

```js
await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"which kubectl"')
// ''
await window.electronAPI.shell.which('kubectl')
// {error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'stdout')"}
await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"command -v kubectl"')
// ''
console.log(await window.electronAPI.shell.exec('"ls"'))
/*
Applications
Library
System
Users
Volumes
bin
*/
```

### My Research about sandboxing

The scripts runs on the main process of the electron.

> - The main process runs in a Node.js environment, meaning it has the ability to require modules and use all of Node.js APIs. [[Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-main-process)]
> - Note that as in Chromium, the main (browser) process is privileged and cannot be sandboxed. [[Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox)]

### IPC communication

I'm using [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate with renderer process (my vue spa).

```js
// electron.js (main process)
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron') // electron": "^16.2.5
const shell = require('shelljs') //  "shelljs": "^0.8.5",

// <...>
// create BrowserWindow
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
//<...>

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  ipcMain.handle('shell:which', async (event, ...args) => {
    return shell.which(...args).catch(e => ({ error: e.message }))
  })
  ipcMain.handle('shell:exec', async (event, script) => {
    return childProcessWithResult(['-c', script])
      .then(result => result.trim())
      .catch(e => ({ error: e.message }))
  })
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})
```

```js
// preload.js (renderer process)
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  shell: {
    which: (...args) => ipcRenderer.invoke('shell:which', ...args),
    exec: (script) => ipcRenderer.invoke('shell:exec', script)
  }
})
```

I grant File Access and Developer Tools Permission to my app, (by Security & Privacy)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you have modified as well as the code you're using to communicate with the renderer. Thanks!

Comment: I added my code to execute shell script and IPC communications. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved!! I don't know what to say. :) But I will try.

As we know, Electron doesn't sandbox the main process. The reason is just the `PATH` variable.

In Windows PowerShell, I can't see the problem. Why? Because the `PATH` environment variables are saved in `Windows Registry`. It is independent of PowerShell.

But in UNIX(like Mac OS, and Linux), they are set when the shell is initiated with `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`.

When I click the packaged app icon, to execute the application... shell is not initiated. No Environment Variables. No `PATH`. The Shell can not find our cli programs!

But we can read the content of `~/xxshrc`. So I just execute the script, and get the PATH variable, then set it to `process.env.PATH` with other defaults (like brew path).

Next is the code.

```js
const env = await childProcessWithResult('zsh -ic export')
const PATH = env.split('\n')
                .find(s => s.startsWith('PATH'))
                .replace('PATH=', '')
process.env.PATH = [
  '/usr/local/bin',
  '/opt/homebrew/bin',
  '/opt/homebrew/sbin',
  '/usr/local/go/bin',
  '/Library/Apple/usr/bin',
  '/Applications/Privileges.app/Contents/Resources',
  PATH
].join(':')
```

Comment: update: just use [fix path](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path)